# NetSSL Dependencies?

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

Which other libraries do I need to compile for NetSSL library? Of course, it needs OpenSSL but I only mean Poco Libraries. Is Poco Foundation oder Poco Utilities required to build my project which includes NetSSL?

Answer (score 1):

NetSSL needs PocoNet, PocoCrypto, PocoUtil, PocoXML and PocoFoundation. The dependency to PocoUtil (and therefore also PocoXML) is a bit annoying, but that's the way it is...